# Marketing Cloud: Permission Denied for API Endpoints / Objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, sfmc-business-unit

Within Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget), when accessing the BusinessRule object via the SOAP API, I am getting a permission denied error. I possess the unmodified and original roles for: Admin, Marketing Cloud Admin, Marketing Cloud Security Admin.

This are what I cannot access:

- SOAP API: [BusinessRule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/businessrule.html?q=Businessrule) object

I have tested using a web app integration possessing all scopes, and and I have also tested using username and password directly also. Are there secret restrictions on the aforementioned objects/endpoints? I have made sure I have the permissions detailed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but only Salesforce support can access and update the business rules in a Marketing Cloud account. It makes sense to me since every change in the business rules has a big impact on the MC account.

In case, you are curious about available business rules then [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fv0Oo7WK45IrKL21sY8SmUjH1FjCZByWDj0ibk4IsAU/edit#gid=0) is what [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) found and shared.